# SharePoint Closed web part

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, tracking, history

I have a site developed in MOSS2007. where can I see the list of web parts that are closed and the user name who closed that web parts i.e. (ClosedBy).

Or else, if a particular web part is closed, how can I get to know that web part is closed by whom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only see that the web part has been closed and you can restore it from the closed web parts gallery (when you open the web part addition window, just click on Advanced at the bottom and then select the first gallery in the pane)
You cannot know who closed the web part. If you do not want people to close web part, just take away this permission.

Comment: hi Vladi Gubler,
Thanks for your quick reply but I can't remove the permission of deleting the web part. is there any way where I can see created by for closed web part?, As It shown in recycle bin after deleting the document, list or any other content on sharePoint site. Any help will be appreciable!

Comment: No, it does not go to the recycle bin, it goes to the closed web parts gallery, the event itself is not registered anywhere. The only thing i could suggest is picking up the change in the page's web part structure using as hidden control placed on the page and log that into a list. You would need to develop such a control.